# Handling Non-Integer Input in a Guessing Game with an 'Invalid Entry' Message

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a simple guessing game in Python and need to display an "Invalid entry" message when the user inputs anything other than an integer. I'm facing a syntax error and am unsure of the correct approach to validate integer input.

Here's the part of my code related to handling the input:

```
import random

while True:
    hidden = random.randrange(1, 5)
    try:
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 5: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Entry. Please enter an integer between 1 and 5.")
        continue

    # Rest of the guessing logic...
```

I've attempted to use an if statement to check if the input is an integer, but I'm encountering a syntax error. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I correctly check if the user's input is an integer and prompt an "Invalid entry" message for non-integer inputs?

Are there any best practices in Python for handling this type of input validation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string to a float or int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)

Comment: You forgot to add colon `:` after if condition,  therefore a syntax error arises

Comment: alright, I fixed the missing `:` after the `if` statement. Now I'm getting an the message ```
Invalid Entry. Please enter an Integer between 1 and 5: ``` even after entering any number at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set a conditional in python based on datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113187/how-do-you-set-a-conditional-in-python-based-on-datatypes)

Comment: You would be better off using the routine `sanitised_input` given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/6246044). In particular, call `sanitised_input('Guess a number between 1 and 5:', type_=int, min_=1, max_=5)`. Or perhaps `sanitised_input('Guess a number between 1 and 5:', range_=[1,2,3,4,5])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to verify that the user entry is an int, you want to keep the input in string form. Then write a small function to test the input. Here, I'll use a list comprehension and the string join and isdigit methods, to ensure the user has only entered digits 0-9 in the string, i.e. then this function returns True (else False) (*modified as per Jack Taylor comment below, also for s = '' case):

```
def testForInt(s):
    if s:
        try:
            _ = s.encode('ascii')
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            return False
        test = ''.join([x for x in s if x.isdigit()])
        return (test == s)
    else:
        return False
```

If you want to sandbox the user entirely, wrap it in a loop like this:

```
acceptable = False
while not acceptable:
    entry = input("Enter an int: ")
    if testForInt(entry):
        entry = int(entry)
        acceptable = True
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")
```

If you want a simpler version with no function call(see Jack Taylor comment), this works too:

```
acceptable = False
while not acceptable:
    entry = input("Enter an int: ")
    try:
        entry = int(entry)
        acceptable = True
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Failed due to {str(e)}")
```

Now you've got what you know is an int, with no worries. This kind of approach to verifying user entry saves many headaches if consistently implemented. See SQL injection etc.

Comment: This approach suffers the same drawback as @Deepankar's. If you input a string like "①", then it will pass the testForInt function, but the program will raise an exception when you actually try to convert it to an int.

Comment: @JackTaylor thanks, I tried a string encode('ascii') method inside a try/except block which seems to work...

Comment: Why not use int(entry) inside a try/except block? That seems a lot simpler to me.

Comment: Perfect This is what I needed thanks @neureino_logic

Comment: Yes that's simpler... coming from C++ to Python, I think makes me more reluctant to use exceptions than is the 'pythonic' standard. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this method to check if something is not an integer:

Python 3

```py
if not round(guess) == guess: print("Do Stuff")
```

Python 2

```py
if not round(guess) == guess: print "Do Stuff"
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I'm looking for. I just need a conditional statement catching everything that is not an integer and outputting a message "Invalid Entry" and they return to prompt for another try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
play = True

while play:
    guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 5: ")

    try:
        number = int(guess)
    except ValueError:
        print("You need to input an integer.")
        continue

    if number < 1 or number > 5:
        print("You need to input an integer between 1 and 5.")
        continue

    # ...

    print("Your number was: " + guess)
    play = False
```

When you first use `input()`, you get a string back. If you try to turn that string into an integer straight away by doing `int(input())`, and if the player types a string like "abcd", then Python will raise an exception.

```
>>> int(input("Guess a number: "))
Guess a number: abcd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abcd'
```

To avoid this, you have to handle the exception by doing `int(guess)` inside a [try/except block](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/).

The [continue statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) skips back to the start of the while loop, so if you use it you can get away with only having to ask for input once.

Comment: I was able to get it to now work for values below 1 and above 5
But when I enter strings it's still spitting out error messages.                                                        is there a way for this to print out the "Invalid Entry" message when strings are entered like just a letter or a word?

Comment: Did you copy and paste my example code with no alterations? It should print "You need to input an integer" if you input a string.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the user input as string to avoid `ValueError`.

```py
guess = input("Guess a number between 1 and 5: ")

while not guess.isdigit() or int(guess) > 5 or int(guess) < 1: 
    guess = input("Invalid Entry. Please enter an Integer between 1 and 5: ")

guess = int(guess)
```

Above code ensures that user input is a positive integer and between 1 and 5. Next, convert the user input to integer for further use.

Additionally, if you want to check the data type of a python object/variable then use the `isinstance` method. Example:

```
a = 2
isinstance(a, int)

Output:
>>> True
```

Comment: This breaks for Unicode characters that are classified as digits but can't be converted to an int in Python. For instance, `"①".isdigit()` is True, but `int("①")` raises a ValueError.

Comment: @JackTaylor, Thanks! I was not aware of that. However, a typical user won't input Unicode characters like this unless they are adamant on breaking the program.