# How to prrint the Data Type in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have written a simple code to know the Data type of input.
Here is my code.
I gave 2  inputs that are getting convert as a "String". Using the "If" condition to match inputs data type. But my output is weird. I don't know why it is printing the only integer here. Can anyone help me to solve this?

I have added my output also here

Code:

```
a=str(input("Enter A Value \n"))
b=str(input("Enter B value \n"))
print('\n')
print('A is = ',a)
print('B is = ',b)

if (type(a)==int, type(b)==int):
print('A and B is Integer')

elif (a==str, b==str):
    print('A and B is String')

elif (a==float, b==float):
    print('\nA and B is Float')

print('\n*Program End*')'
```

**Output**:

```
Enter A Value 
abc
Enter B value 
def


A is =  abc
B is =  def

A and B is Integer

*Program End*
```

Comment: Given that: 1. `input` gives you a string; and 2. you then explicitly pass that to `str`, why is it unclear what the data types of `a` and `b` are?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine a Python variable's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type)

Comment: @jonrsharpe and all the comparisons are only testing the truthfulness of a non-empty tuple.....

Comment: You may want to ``print((type(a)==int, type(b)==int))`` (note the required double parentheses) to see what you are actually checking. Also note that containers with at least one element are considered true.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi - I tried in your way. But still, my output is same "A and B is Integer"

My question is : I know i gave string values there. But I want to match through "elif " statements and I wish to get the output as "A and B as String" there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if input is float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807810/how-to-check-if-input-is-float-or-int)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
if (type(a)==int, type(b)==int)
```

**^** this goes for all the `if` conditions you have.

That is not the way to use multiple condition on an `if` statement. In fact, that is just a `tuple`. So you are saying `if (0,0)`. So. According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=truth%20value%20testing#truth-value-testing)

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
>   either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method
>   that returns zero, when called with the object. 1 Here are most of the
>   built-in objects considered false:
>
> ```
> - constants defined to be false: None and False.
> - zero of any numeric type: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
> - empty sequences and collections: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)
> ```

In this case you are using a `tuple` with `len() != 0` so it will always return `True` when checked its truth value. So the correct way to check multiple truth conditions is using [boolean operators](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=truth%20value%20testing#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

```
a=str(input("Enter A Value \n"))
b=str(input("Enter B value \n"))
print('\n')
print('A is = ',a)
print('B is = ',b)

if type(a)==int and type(b)==int:
    print('A and B is Integer')
elif type(a)==str and type(b)==str:
    print('A and B is String')
elif type(a)==float and type(b)==float:
    print('\nA and B is Float')

print('\n*Program End*')
```

**^** Note I added `type()` to the other conditions because they weren't present.

Now. There is another issue here:

```
a=str(input("Enter A Value \n"))
b=str(input("Enter B value \n"))
```

You are converting to `str` the input, which is already an `str` because `input` give you `str`, so you will always get:

`A and B is String`

Because they are both `str`. So you could use `str` built-in functions for this:

```
if a.isnumeric() and b.isnumeric():
    print('A and B is Integer')
elif a.isalpha() and b.isalpha():
    print('A and B is String')
elif a.replace('.','',1).isdigit() and b.replace('.','',1).isdigit():
    print('\nA and B is Float')
```

The first one is [`a.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isnumeric), then [`a.alpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isalpha) and for last a workaround to check if it is `float`: replace the `.` for a 1 and check if it remains as [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isdigit).

Answer (score 2):

(I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for) You can print the data type of something in python using the type() function like so:

```
var = 25
print(type(var))
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1):

type() method will return class type

```
a=5
print(a,"is type of",type(a))
b=2.9
print(b,"is type of",type(b))
c='Hello'
print(c,"is type of",type(c))
```

Output:

```
5 is type of <class 'int'>
2.9 is type of <class 'float'>
Hello is type of <class 'str'>
```

Comment: I want to match the data type with my input. I gave String as input. When I am using the "elif" statement, I am checking my input data type and expecting the output is only "String". But it is giving as "Integer" and program ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
integer=100
print(integer,"is a",type(integer))
string="Python"
print(string,"is a",type(string))
decimal=5.973 #decimal is also called  as float.
print(decimal,"is a",type(decimal))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
100 is a <class 'int'>
Python is a <class 'str'>
5.973 is a <class 'float'>
```