# How to recognize if a input is a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a calculator in python 3 and I'm wondering if there is an option that can tell if the input the user gave is not a float.
For example if the user wrote a word instead of a float the code will recognize it and print out something like:

```
if num1 != float:
    print("You Need To Enter A Number")
```

Comment: Do you actually care about float or just if it's numeric (i.e. float or int)?

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns everything in `str` type. You need to manually test by conversion

```py
def is_float(number):
    try:
        float(number)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

number = input()
print(is_float(number))
```

Comment: This will say that `12` is a float though, which might not be what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

I'd just keep it simple. If it contains a dot, say it's a float.

```
number = input('Number: ')

if '.' in number:
    try:
        value = float(number)
        # Number is a float.
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input')
else:
    try:
        value = int(number)
        # Number is an integer.
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input')
```

Although, the best way is probably to use `ast.literal_eval` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819829/6486738).