# regex doesn't seem to work in allowRegexes parameter when using pyinputplus

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am using pyinputplus and specifically inputNum
https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

This is what my code looks like:

```
msg = 'Enter value to add/replace or s to skip field or q to quit: '
answer = pyip.inputNum(prompt=msg, allowRegexes=r'^[qQsS]$', blank=False)
```

My goal is to allow any number but also allow one of the following q,Q,s,S.

However when I run the code and enter 'sam' the code crashes because later on I am trying to convert to float(answer).

My expectation is that allowRegexes will not allow this and will show me the prompt again to re-enter.
Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `pyip.inputNum` stops validating the input if you provide `allowRegexes`  argument. See the [*`allowRegexes` doesn't seem work properly*](https://github.com/asweigart/pyinputplus/issues/20) Github issue.

You can use the `inputCustom` method with a custom validation method:

```py
import pyinputplus as pyip
import ast

def is_numeric(x):
    try:
        number = ast.literal_eval(x)
    except:
        return False
    return isinstance(number, float) or isinstance(number, int)

def raiseIfInvalid(text):
    if not is_numeric(text) and not text.casefold() in ['s', 'q']:
        raise Exception('Input must be numeric or "q"/"s".')

msg = 'Enter value to add/replace or s to skip field or q to quit: '
answer = pyip.inputCustom(raiseIfInvalid, prompt=msg)
```

So, if the `text` is not and `int` or `float` and not equal to `s`/`S`/`q`/`Q`, the prompt will repeat showing up.

Comment: thanks @Wiktor Stribizew. do you know how to check in the custom exception and allow floats. i believe isnumeric doesnt allow decimal points

Comment: @trustory There are a lot of such resources, see [Check if a number is int or float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541155/check-if-a-number-is-int-or-float). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4541207/3832970) may help. Or, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807810/how-to-check-if-input-is-float-or-int).

Comment: Stribizew would this work too?


if not string.replace(",","").isnumeric()

Comment: @trustory I added the full code snippet. Does it work for you now?