# How to check Datatype with if else in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I want to check my Datatype in python using `if else`**

**Output I want :** *If user Enter float Datatype so it print `It is float` or if user enter another `Datatype` so it print `it is not float`*

**Code:**

```
c=(input("Enter the value\n"))
if type (c) == float:
    print('it is float')
else:
   print("it is not float")
```

**Output I want:**

```
Enter the value
12.1
it is float
```

**Output I'm getting:**

*If I enter `float datatype` it is still printing `it is else`*

```
Enter the value
12.1
it is else
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The `input()` function *always* returns an object of type `str`. You can convert it to other types yourself if you want to.

Comment: `c` is always `str`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if input is float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807810/how-to-check-if-input-is-float-or-int)

Comment: so what can I do? if I use ```c=float(input("Enter a number")``` so it always show float. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
c=input("Enter the value\n")
try:
    float(c)
    print('it is float')
except ValueError:
   print("it is not float")
```

your problem is that input always give you str value so by trying to convert it to float you know if its a float or not

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this

```
c = (input("Enter the value\n"))
try:
    f = float(c)
    is_float = True
except ValueError:
    is_float = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if object is int or float: `isinstance()`

The type of an object can be obtained with the built-in function type().

```
i = 100
f = 1.23

print(type(i))
print(type(f))
# <class 'int'>
# <class 'float'>
```

The built-in function isinstance(object, type) can be used to determine whether an object is of a particular type.

Get / determine the type of an object in Python: `type()`, `isinstance()`

```
print(isinstance(i, int))
# True

print(isinstance(i, float))
# False

print(isinstance(f, int))
# False

print(isinstance(f, float))
# True
```

In this case, since only the type is checked, it cannot be determined whether the value of float is an integer (the fractional part is 0).

```
f_i = 100.0

print(type(f_i))
# <class 'float'>

print(isinstance(f_i, int))
# False

print(isinstance(f_i, float))
# True
source: check_int_float.py
Check if float is integer: is_integer()
float has is_integer() method that returns True if the value is an integer, and False otherwise.

f = 1.23

print(f.is_integer())
# False

f_i = 100.0

print(f_i.is_integer())
# True
```

For example, a function that returns True for an integer number (int or integer float) can be defined as follows. This function returns False for str.

```
def is_integer_num(n):
    if isinstance(n, int):
        return True
    if isinstance(n, float):
        return n.is_integer()
    return False

print(is_integer_num(100))
# True

print(is_integer_num(1.23))
# False

print(is_integer_num(100.0))
# True

print(is_integer_num('100'))
# False
```

Credits: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-check-int-float/

Comment: It is absolutely the case that one should use `isinstance()` rather than checking the return of `type()`. Thanks for bringing that up. However, in this case `input()` always returns a string so we can't really use `isinstance()` in the way we hope and a cast to float can throw an error so we really need an answer built around `try:`