# How can I fix VS Code error "invalid literal for int() with base 10"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input, integer

```
var1 = 6
var2 = int(input())
if var2 > var1:
    print("Greater")
else:
    print("Smaller")
```

Hey there I started learning python recently, currently I am using VS Code but I encountered a problem while learning IF ELSE, in the above code it is showing "invalid literal for int() with base 10" while in other compiler it works fine. How do I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819829/2264936) helps out.

Or you may first float() the input() and then do the int().
You should also indicate in the input() which type of number you expect, like 8 or 8.8 or both.

```
var1 = 6
inp = input('Enter a number(e.g. 8 or 8.8):')
print(type(inp))
inpf = float(inp)
print(type(inpf))
var2 = int(inpf)
if var2 > var1:
    print("Greater")
else:
    print("Smaller")
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
var1 = 6
var2 = float(input())
if var2 > var1:
    print("Greater")
else:
    print("Smaller")
```

`int()` only accepts integer.