# How do I force a string to a type and if it raises a TypeError, dismiss it and return a message?

Tags: python

Problem:
I want to take user input (string) and convert into a float. If the input is a letter or symbol that can't be converted into type float, I want it to print a message and force the user to rewrite a valid input.

What I've tried:
I know how to do inputs, type conversions etcetera, but I can't seem to manage a way to bypass a TypeError. I can convert a string in the form of "8.2" into float and then it works fine, but I can't get pass the instant crash when the TypeError occurs after trying to convert a non-number.

Code:

```py
a = float(input("Number to add: "))
if a == type(float):
     displaySum = add(displaySum, float(a))
     print(round(displaySum))
elif a != type(float):
     print("Invalid input")
# this works if a letter/symbol is the input, but not if a number is the input, as it checks for type(float) before it's converted to float.
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if input is float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807810/how-to-check-if-input-is-float-or-int)

Comment: Note, all of your conditions are nonsensicle, `a == type(float)` will *never* be true. `type(float)` is `type`, i.e. the standard metaclass (class of a class). And note, it comes *after* you try to convert the string to a `float`, so there's no pointin checking, either an error would be raised or `a` will be a float`. You check the type of an object by using `isinstance(some_object, SomeType)` or `type(some_object) is SomeType`

Answer (score 0):

You should look up pythons [try/except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

a = float(input("Number to add: "))

try:

```
 displaySum = add(displaySum, float(a))

 print(round(displaySum))
```

except:

print("Invalid Input")