# isinstance behavior incorrect?

Tags: python-3.x, isinstance

Here is the output from debug console

```
self.functionList = [regression(2)]
self.functionList
Out[1]: [<regression at 0x2530370a2c8>]
type(self.functionList)
Out[2]: list
isinstance(type(self.functionList), list)
Out[3]: False
type(self.functionList) == list
Out[4]: True
import typing
isinstance(type(self.functionList), typing.List)
Out[16]: False
```

I am confused as in why `isinstance` function returns `False` even though the variable `functionList` is clearly an instance of type `list`.

What is the issue with `isinstance` behavior?

Comment: ``isinstance(type(self.functionList), list)`` checks whether the *type* of ``self.functionList`` is an instance of ``list``. Only ``self.functionList`` *itself* is an instance of ``list``. ``isinstance(self.functionList, list)`` should be ``True``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set a conditional in python based on datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113187/how-do-you-set-a-conditional-in-python-based-on-datatypes)

Comment: thanks! That was rather a silly mistake on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the wrong ones. Try this code.

```
import typing
isinstance(self.functionList, typing.List)
```

For `isinstance` method, compare the object with the expected type. For more info, refer the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).