# Check if an item is an instance but not a subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, isinstance

How can you check if an object is an instance of a class but not any of its subclasses (without knowing the names of the subclasses)?
So if I had the below code:

```
def instance_but_not_subclass(object, class):
    #code
    return result

class item(object):
    
class item_2(item):

...

class item_n(item): 

a = item()
b = item_2()
...
c = item_n()

instance_but_not_subclass(a, item)
instance_but_not_subclass(b, item)
...
instance_but_not_subclass(c, item)
```

what would go in the `#code` space that would produce the output?:

```
True
False
...
False
```

Because `issubclass()` and `isinstance()` always return `True`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set a conditional in python based on datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113187/how-do-you-set-a-conditional-in-python-based-on-datatypes)

Comment: TLDR: ``def instance_but_not_subclass(obj, cls): return type(obj) is cls``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `object.__class__` attribute is a reference to the exact class of an object, so you only need to compare that with your argument

```py
def instance_but_not_subclass(obj, klass):
    return obj.__class__ is klass
```

Don't name variables `class`, its a keyword and won't work, use `klass`or `typ` instead. Also, the variable name `object` shadows the build in `object`, so use something like `obj`.

---

I personally like the `.__class__` variant more, but the more "pythonic" variant would probably be

```py
def instance_but_not_subclass(object, klass):
    return type(obj) is klass
```

because it doesn't access any dunder (`__`) attributes.