# Python OOP datatype

Tags: python, oop, python-class

Why does it say 'Die eingegebenen Daten haben den falschen Datentyp!' when the datatypes are actually right? Doesn't even work with just matrNr... Although I checked my input of matrNr to be an int?!

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.matrNr = -1
        self.vorname = ''
        self.nachname = ''
        self.gebDatum = []
        self.email = ''
        self.telNr = ''

    def DatenUebergeben(self, matrNr, vorname, nachname, gebDatum, telNr):  
        if matrNr == int and vorname == str and nachname == str and gebDatum == list and telNr == str:
            print('richtige Datentypen!')
        else:
            print('Die eingegebenen Daten haben den falschen Datentyp!')

student1 = Student()
student1.DatenUebergeben(12345,'linda','f',[2,2,1995],'12345')
```

Comment: Please paste the code into your question and don't link a screenshot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set a conditional in python based on datatypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113187/how-do-you-set-a-conditional-in-python-based-on-datatypes)

Comment: TLDR: Use ``isinstance(matrNr, int)`` instead of ``matrNr == int`` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Background

By checking (for example) `matrNr == int` you actually compare the variable `matNr`, which is an `int` (an  instance of `<class 'int'>`) to the class int (`<class 'int'>`).

### Quick fix

You can use the `type()`-function to get the type of a variable, resulting in `type(matrNr) == int`. This does exactly what you are trying to achieve.

### Better solution

In Python you can define the types of variables a function accepts by adding `: <type>` after the argument. The better solution would thus be:

```py
def DatenUebergeben(self, matrNr: int, vorname: str, nachname: str, gebDatum: list, telNr: str):
    # do something
```

Comment: "In Python you can define the types of variables a function accepts by adding ``: <type>`` after the argument." Adding ``: <type>``only creates an **annotation**. It does not cause Python to check whether the types are correct. One needs a separate type checker such as MyPy to check such types, and even then they are not sufficient to check user input at runtime.